# Is there a maximum switching frequency for solar cells ?

Tags: frequency, solar-cell, mppt

I'm wondering what the frequency response of a solar cell is. 
Does a solar cell behave like a low pass filter e.g if i switch a load at 1 MHz, 10 MHz, 100 MHz ? Does the output power decrease if the frequency is too high ?

I'm asking because there exists a Maximum Power Point Tracking Method which is called "Pertub and Observe" . I'm wondering how fast you can change the load and measure the voltage at the load (e.g with a high speed adc) and still get accurate readings.

Will i have problems regarding the frequency response of a solar cell if I change the load 1 Million Times(e.g with a appropriate Transistor) and read the result with a high speed ADC, let's say with 1 Mega Samples per Second.

Comment: What would be the point of using such a ridiculous sample rate? Conditions that affect the output of a solar panel simply don't change anywhere near that fast.

Comment: You say "solar cell" so I think: large cells for converting sunlight into electrical energy. The sun's light intensity changes are quite low in frequency so how would the frequency response matter? **Unless** you mean **photo diode** or **photo transistor** which are light sensitive sensors?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I mean solar cell, yes. 


At both: Yes you are both correct, the environment doesn't change that fast but this is not the reason for my question.  The reason for it is, that the solar panel powers a circuit which needs to be disconnected during the mppt measurement . That means in the meantime the circuit needs to be powered by Capacitors. The shorter the measurement time the smaller the capacitors may be.

I'm aware that there a alternatives, but i'm currently researching the feasibility about this method hence the question regarding the frequency response.

Comment: OK, but then you're not really switching the solar cells themselves then. You're switching the load of the solar cells.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie yes exactly. I should have worded the question a little bit better.

Comment: The wires and frame etc of solar panels probably have a resonant frequency. If you start pulsing them at radio frequencies, you may very well generate RF emissions.

Comment: Normal MPPT systems operate as switching power converters -- the switch turns on and off at a 'high' frequency, limited by noise and switching losses, which is higher than a low frequency limit set by switching capacitor size and voltage droop. And 'perturb and observe' doesn't normally mean disconnecting -- just changing the switching pulse width. It has to be slow enough to see changes in the line current.after line inductance and cell capacitance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solar cells have a [capacitance](http://ims.unipv.it/FIRB2006/pub/Merhej10.pdf), like all diodes, and the leads have an inductance. That will cause a filtering effect at higher frequencies.

But the transistor also has a soft limit on effective switching

Comment: Thank you for the response and the link to the paper. In the paper there is a clear difference between 1kHz and 2.5 kHz. So using extrapolation I assume it will be really bad at 1MHz.

Answer (score 0):

The solar cell is a forward biased diode junction. At one amp, the slope of the resistance is 0.026 / 1amp = 0.026 ohms. If Cjunction (forward bias) is 1uF,
the timeconstant is 26 nanoseconds, or 40/6.28 = 6MHz F3dB.

Now what is the capacitance of a forward-biased solar cell?